# AlphineJS: How handle many different form fields?

Tags: javascript

I have a website that generates with different form fields, like:

```
<form x-data="form()">
 <input type="input" x-model="products[15]quantity"/>
 <input type="checkbox" x-model="products[15][option1]"/>


 <input type="input" x-model="products[75]quantity"/>
 <input type="checkbox" x-model="products[75][option1]"/>
</form>

<script>
function form() {
  return {
    products: {} // not working...
  }
}
</script>
```

But when I run this script then i get many errors, like

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier 'quantity'
```

Comment: @Eldar, typo removed

Comment: Is `products` property an array and has 76 items or more? Or has an item at that index? or  an object with a property named 75 and 15?

Answer (score 2):

You must use `dot` notation or array acces notation `[property]` or `['property']`

Not tested! Back later if I can!

Maybe something like this:

```
<form x-data="form()">
 <input type="input" x-model="products[15].quantity"/> /* note the dot*/
 <input type="checkbox" x-model="products[15].option1"/>


 <input type="input" x-model="products[75].quantity"/>
 <input type="checkbox" x-model="products[75].option1"/>
</form>

<script>
function form() {
  return {
    products: {
       15:{quantity:15,option1='red'},
       75:{quantity:10,option1='blue'},
    } 
  }
}
</script>
```

Update: From comment below I couldn't undertand your problem. But maybe something with `fetch`.

```
<form x-data="form()">
 <template x-for=product in products>
  <input type="input" x-model="product.quantity"/> /* note the dot*/
  <input type="checkbox" x-model="product.option1"/>
 </template>
</form>

<script>
function form() {
  return {
    products: [],
    init() {
        fetch('/products/')
          .then(response => response.json())
          .then(response => this.products = response;)
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

`fetch('/products/')` - is a url/page in url site that return a list of products as json object.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But the "problem" is: is this possible with no repeat of all products in the javascript, to prevent double code? Thats why I tried return { products: {} } but that's not working